# Connectedness of an $n$-dimensional topological manifold is kept by removal of open connected subset.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional $(n>1)$ topological manifold (i.e. $M$ is locally Euclidean,second countable Hausdorff) and also connected, with $B$ an open connected subset of $M$.

Prove that $M\setminus B$ is also connected.   (thanks for your interest)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is not true: $M=\mathbb{R}^2; B=(0,1)\times \mathbb{R}$. Then $M\backslash B=(-\infty,0]\times \mathbb{R}\cup [1,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ is not connected.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. Also to be added: the closure of B is assumed to be compact. Thanks for the answer thusfar.

Comment: Hi Rik, perhaps there must be another condition on $B$. Imagine you remove a neighborhood of the equator in a sphere, you get two components left  from the sphere. Perhaps you can add the condition: the boundary of $B$ is connected. I think it will then turn into a problem in general topology.

Comment: Well, yes, let us additionally accept that the boundary of B is connected.

Answer (score 2):

**It is not true.** Let $M$ be any manifold amd $p \in M$. Choose a chart $\phi : U \to V$ around $p$. For suitable $0 < a$ we have

$$W = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid 0 < \lVert x - \phi(p) \rVert < a \} \subset \overline W = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \lVert x - \phi(p) \rVert \le a \} \subset V$$ $W$ is open and connected with compact closure. Let $B = \phi^{-1}(W)$. This is an open and connected subset of $M$ with compact closure. But $M \setminus B$ is not connected. This set has $\{p\}$ as a component.

Comment: Question to Paul Frost: how can {p} be a component of M\B if p belongs to B?

Comment: @RikVerhoestraete   Mr. Paul Frost has clearly stated that $0<||x-\phi(p)||<a$, which means $p\in M\setminus B$, see the third line and the definition of the set $B$. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I misread the correct definition of W. All my thanks to Caffeine, orangehead and especially Paul Frost and Kevin. S. Things are clear now.